# WPF: Object doesn't exist in namespace

Tags: wpf, namespaces

I have got an object in `App.xaml.cs` as you can see here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Test_Project
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            //Startup
            Window main = new MainWindow();
            main.Show();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Global values for use during application runtime
    /// </summary>
    public class runtimeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

        }
     ....
```

I'm trying to create an instance of the object for use for the duration my application is running. I'm creating this instance in the XAML in `App.xaml`

```
<Application x:Class="Test_Project.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Project">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:runtimeObject x:Key="runtimeVariables" />

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I'm getting the error saying that my class doesn't exist in the namespace. However the xmlns:local does reference the namespace which contains the object, any ideas ?

Comment: tried re-building the solution ? :)

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work, get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops, the `<local:runtimeObject x:Key="runtimeVariables" />` had to go in the `<ResourceDictionary>` and then I had to rebuild the solution.